# PowerShell: New-Timespan format result

Tags: powershell

When I´m using the folling PowerShell code, I´m getting results like 123.0000232 for example.

Is is there a paramter to format the result?

I want a result like 123

```
$TimeStart = Get-Date
#some code
sleep 2
(New-TimeSpan -Start $TimeStart -End $(Get-Date)).TotalSeconds
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

You could do one of two things:

Use the seconds attribute, which is an int32

```
(New-TimeSpan -Start $TimeStart -End $(Get-Date)).Seconds
```

*or* Typecast TotalSeconds to [int32] (not so nice, but works too)

```
[int32] (New-TimeSpan -Start $TimeStart -End $(Get-Date)).TotalSeconds
```

Comment: `.Seconds` will give the wrong answer. If `.TotalSeconds`==123.01, then `.Minutes`==2 and `.Seconds`==3.